# Does the method inside the IF condition always get executed? C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
if (condition) 
{
  // block of code to be executed if the condition is True
}
```

**So if I have a method which returns boolean and the method is used as the condition for IF, does that method get executed no matter what?**

Below is the code I'm working on:

```
public virtual void WorkTheNextShift(float HoneyConsumed)
{
    if (HoneyVault.ConsumeHoney(HoneyConsumed))
    {
        DoJob();
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("Not enough honey left!");
}
```

This is the ConsumeHoney method in the static HoneyVault class:

```
public static bool ConsumeHoney(float amount)
{
    if (amount < honey)
    {
        honey -= amount;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

**Additional question:
Is there any official documentation where it says that the condition inside IF will always be executed? I can't seem to find it under Microsoft's .NET documentation, or anywhere else.**

Comment: Yes.  The example of calling ConsumeHoney( parameterValue ) will be called each time.

Comment: In your example, yes. But `||` and `&&` are short circuit operators. Evaluation stops as soon as the result is clear. Which is why something like `if (x != null && x.something...)` doesn't throw a null reference exception.

Comment: C# is the language so its documentation — not .NET's — is what you'd consult for `if` statements.  In `if (condition)` the `condition` is always evaluated because the whole point of `if` is to take action based on the value of `condition` so how could it _not_ evaluate it?  Whether `condition` consists of one or multiple `bool` expressions and whether all or less than all of them get evaluated is another matter not defined by or specific to `if` statements.  Also, unless you really want `ConsumeHoney()` to always leave at least _some_ amount of honey, you probably meant `if (amount <= honey)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, yes: the method will always get executed.

Things can get a little more complex if you have multiple conditions. In this case something called [short-circuit evaluation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/) may come into play and the method may not be executed at all if the boolean condition can be satisfied regardless of it's result.

The following examples will help clarify it:

```
bool A = true;
bool B = false;
bool Test() {
    Console.WriteLine("Test was called!");
    return false;
}

if (Test()) {
    // will call Test
}

if (B || Test()) {
    // will call Test since B is false the compiler has to check Test()
}

if (A || Test()) {
    // Test won't be called because A is true and the result 
    // of Test() is not needed. The condition is always true.
}

if (B && Test()) {
    // Test won't be called because B is false and the result 
    // of Test() is not needed. The condition is always false.
}

if (A && Test()) {
    // Will call Test since A is true. The compiler needs to check the
    // result of Test to properly check the AND condition.
}
```

In the official documentation the `&&` operator is described as: *The conditional logical AND operator &&, also known as the "short-circuiting" logical AND operator*.

While the `||` operator is described as: *The conditional logical OR operator ||, also known as the "short-circuiting" logical OR operator*

Here is a link to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask if there exists any official documentation or resource for this sort of questions that I can refer to and try to find answers myself? Thanks again!

Comment: @Programmer you need to learn how to debug, its the best thing for a developer! Watch a YouTube video on C# Debugging, setting breakpoints, stepping through each line of code F11, Stepping Into Functions F11, Stepping over functions F10, running to next breakpoint F5, the Immediate Window Ctrl Alt I and walking the CallStack Ctrl Alt L. Also worth learning how to navigate your code with F12 to goto Definition and Ctrl **-** to go back to the last thing you were looking at.

Comment: @Programmer Another simple shortcut is if you're using VS, just press F1 when the cursor is in the keyword or class you're learning, it should take straight to the official docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any documentation where it says the condition inside IF will always be executed? I can't find it under .NET documentation for some reason.

Comment: @Programmer I've already updated the answer with a link to the documentation. Take special attention when they explain "short-circuiting".